# JSON from get request not returning properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, heroku

I'm running a Heroku server and I'm trying to change the innerHTML on my website to display certain statistics gathered from an endpoint on the server:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

var element = document.getElementById('change');
element.innerHTML = xhr.valueinJSON;

function processRequest(e) {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    alert(response.ip);
  }
}
```

My script tag contains the above and although the endpoint works properly in Postman, the JSON is always null. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you run `console.log(xhr.responseText)` and show the result in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `valueinJSON` is from an API I'm not familiar with, but I can't find a reference to it. Either way, you need to change your `innerHTML` in the async function like this:

```
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
   var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
   var element = document.getElementById('change');
   element.innerHTML = response

}
```

You are trying to set the `innerHTML` before the browser has a chance to download it.

This assumes there is not a CORS issue. You should check your browser's console to make sure there are not errors.